# IOS Container View VC dismiss parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 view controllers. Controller A calls B. B has a container view which contains C - a table view controller. How do I use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in C to dismiss both B and C and return to A?

I've tried this:

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

this:

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

None of which work.

Comment: It sounds like it's C's parent that needs to do the  dismissing, but it's not clear from your post where the navigation controller fits in. Did you try [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; or, [self.parentViewController.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I believe so, I've found a different solution though. I made the parent (B) a delegate of C and implemented the dataFromController method. Inside that method I put the code "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];". Since I'm using ARC, does this automatically free up memory of C?